# How to Checked Option Bottomn with stored data in database

Tags: php, laravel

i use laravel 4.2,
in my project, i use option bottomn, data stored in database :

1. id = 1    | title = base1
2. id = 2    | title = base2

now, how can i in this code, checked option btn with data stored :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="radio-list">
      @foreach($base as $ba)
         <label for="base-label-{{$ba->id}}">
            <div class="radio" id="label-{{$ba->id}}"><input type="radio" name="base" id="base-label-{{$ba->id}}" value="{{$ba->id}}"  {{ !empty($ba->id)  ? 'checked' : '' }}></div> {{$ba->title}}
         </label>
      @endforeach
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have the retrieved `id` data from database as `$ba_id`, you could compare it lik this :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="radio-list">
        @foreach($base as $ba)
            <label for="base-label-{{$ba->id}}">
                <div class="radio" id="label-{{$ba->id}}"><input type="radio" name="base" id="base-label-{{$ba->id}}" value="{{$ba->id}}"  {{ !empty($ba->id) && ($ba_id == $ba->id)  ? 'checked' : '' }}></div> {{$ba->title}}
            </label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```